# Is it mandatory to use the isAuthorized() method in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am using `cakephp 2.6.9.` and I'm trying to log in using [auth](/questions/tagged/auth), but it shows:

```
$controller does not implement an isAuthorized() method
```

Is it mandatory to use the `isAuthorized()` method in [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Auth component with the [ControllerAuthorize](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-ControllerAuthorize.html#37) authorization adapter yes. If you want to use something else use one of the other adapters or write your own.

See [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authorization) for a basic introduction on how the auth component works.